# anyone understands how to make the bottom menu like this, which looks like FAB and under it there is another icon. also the fab icon cannot be changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I'm having trouble creating a Qris fab icon without a corner effect on the bottom navigation. And there is also a menu image below the fab button. And I also have difficulty when changing the icon on the fab, when using png files, all I get is a black image.